# Prob: Moment Generating Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I found the moment generating function of $W=4Y-2$ which is $e^{-2t} * e^{(3*((e^{4t}) -1))}$.
Is this moment generating function poissonly distributed? And Why?

Comment: The formula is not clear. Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson distribution is not closed under affine transformations, meaning the random variable

$W = 4Y -2$ with $Y\sim \operatorname{Pois}(3)$ is not a Poisson rv.

At MGF level one can see this, because the MGF of $W$ cannot be transformed so as to "look like" a Poissonian MGF.
At moment level we have

$$E(W) = 4E(Y) - 2 = 4\cdot 3 -2 = 10$$
and
$$\operatorname{Var} (W) = 16\operatorname{Var}(Y) = 16\cdot 3 = 48$$

So $E(W) \neq \operatorname{Var}(W)$, and this is sufficient to conclude that $W$ does not follow the Poisson.